# Combining the depth and color data

Tags: ros, openni, libopenni, freenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the following piece of code for acquiring depth as well as the color data from kinect. I would now like to use the depth information to extract some points/pixel in the color image after a keyboard input ('c')
a) What is the best way to pass information from callback2 to callback ?
b) How do I ensure that the depth data(callback2) is obtained before callback is executed?

### Thanks,

```
import roslib
import sys
import rospy
import cv2
from std_msgs.msg import String
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
import numpy as np
import math;
import cv2;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
import sys;
import caffe;
import socket;

class image_converter:

  def __init__(self):
    cv2.namedWindow("Image window", 1)
    print 'start bridge and subscribe'
    self.bridge = CvBridge()
    self.depth_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/camera/depth_registered/image_raw",Image,self.callback2,queue_size=1)
    self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/camera/rgb/image_color",Image,self.callback,queue_size=1)


  def callback2(self,data):
    try:
        depth_image_raw = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "passthrough")
        depth_image = depth_image_raw.astype(np.uint8)
        cv2.imshow("Depth window", depth_image)
        key = cv2.waitKey(3)
        if (key == 99): # 'c'
            # save depth data as numpy array

    except CvBridgeError, e:
      print e


  def callback(self,data):

    try:
      image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
    except CvBridgeError, e:
      print e

    cv_image = image[:,:,:];

    if (key == 99): # 'c'
       # Use the depth data and get the corresponding points in the color image

def main(args):
  ic = image_converter()
  rospy.init_node('image_converter', anonymous=True)
  try:
    rospy.spin()
      except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Shutting down"
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215152/combining-the-depth-and-color-data/) by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2015-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use message filters to synchronize the topics.
http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters

(I never used that with python, btw.)

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) on 2015-08-04**:
Thanks. ApproximateTimeSynchronizer(python) is added in the indigo version

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-08-04**:
You're welcome ;-)